Unmarshal xml into custom struct - how to handle different structures for the same tag
I have a .owl like this simplified example:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xml:base="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     xmlns:mc="http://my-company/ontologies#">
    <Ontology rdf:about="http://my-company/ontologies"/>

    <Class rdf:about="http://my-company/ontologies#Thing">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:nodeID="genid494"/>
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
            <Restriction>
                <onProperty rdf:resource="http://my-company/ontologies#myProp1"/>
            </Restriction>
        </rdfs:subClassOf>
    </Class>
    <Restriction rdf:nodeID="genid494">
        <onProperty rdf:resource="http://my-company/ontologies#myProp2"/>
    </Restriction>
</rdf:RDF>

The problem is, that the subClassOf child nodes of Class can either have a reference to a Restriction, or embed a Restriction.
I try to unmarshal the given xml in these target structs:
type RDF struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"RDF"`
    XMLNS    string   `xml:"xmlns,attr"`
    Base     string   `xml:"base,attr"`
    OWLNS    string   `xml:"owl,attr"`
    RDFNS    string   `xml:"rdf,attr"`
    XML      string   `xml:"xml,attr"`
    XSD      string   `xml:"xsd,attr"`
    RDFS     string   `xml:"rdfs,attr"`
    MCNS  string   `xml:"mc,attr"`
    Ontology struct {
        About *string `xml:"about,attr"`
    } `xml:"Ontology"`

    Classes      []Class       `xml:"Class,omitempty"`
    Restrictions []Restriction `xml:"Restriction,omitempty"`
}
type Restriction struct {
    OnProperty ResourceData `xml:"onProperty"`
}
type ResourceData struct {
    Resource string `xml:"resource,attr"`
}
type Class struct {
    ClassDefinition []ClassDescriptor `xml:"subClassOf,omitempty"`
}
type ClassDescriptor struct {
    Restriction *RestrictionReference `xml:"restriction"`
}
type RestrictionReference struct {
    inner     *Restriction
    reference *string
}


My goal is to create RestrictionReference which either hold the Restriction child - if available -, or a reference (and I can add some more function receivers like func (r *RestrictionReference) GetRestriction(rdf RDF) *Restriction it to hide this complexity later on).
My problem is that I fail to implement the xml.Unmarshaler for *ClassDescriptor accordingly. I came up with something like that yet, but I fail to parse the child node if necessary:
func (description *ClassDescriptor) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    // easier case: there is just a reference
    for _, attr := range start.Attr {
        switch attr.Name.Local {
        case "resource":
            cp := attr.Value
            description.Restriction.reference = &cp
        case "nodeID":
            nodeID := attr.Value
            description.Restriction.reference = &nodeID
        default:
            return errors.New("unknown xml attribute:", attr.Name.Local)
        }
    }
    // temporary? workaround to avoid the "did not consume the entire element" err for the easier case
    if len(start.Attr) == 0 {
        return d.Skip()
    } else {
        // complicated case: there is a child node with the Restriction
        // TODO unmarshal Restriction and set it in the RestrictionReference prop
        var redData Restriction
        // will be empty, but I don't know what to pass here instead
        err := d.DecodeElement(&redData, &start)
        description.Restriction.inner = &redData
        return err
    }
}

I have no idea how I can unmarshal the child node. Is my approach even valid?
Edit:
I guess I could just avoid the question with this declaring both possibilities in the ClassDescriptor struct like this:
type ClassDescriptor struct {
    NodeID      *NodeID      `xml:"nodeID,attr"`
    Restriction *Restriction `xml:"Restriction"` 
}

But this renders the handling from outside a bit more messy then I wanted, I still don't know how to actually implement an xml.Unmarshaller which reads a child node.

Your example code does not compile.

Okay, let's simplify that a bit.
Assuming you want to decode
<RDF>
    <Class>
        <subClassOf nodeID="genid494"/>
        <subClassOf>
            <Restriction>
                <onProperty resource="http://my-company/ontologies#myProp1"/>
            </Restriction>
        </subClassOf>
    </Class>
</RDF>

and having an attribute on a subClassOf is a reliable criteria, you could try (Go Playground):
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type RDF struct {
    Classes []Class `xml:"Class"`
}

type Class struct {
    ClassDefinition []ClassDescriptor `xml:"subClassOf"`
}

type ClassDescriptor struct {
    NodeID     string
    OnProperty string
}

func (description *ClassDescriptor) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    if len(start.Attr) > 0 {
        var v struct {
            NodeID string `xml:"nodeID,attr"`
        }
        if err := d.DecodeElement(&v, &start); err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("can't decode node id on %+v: %w", start, err)
        }
        description.NodeID = v.NodeID
    } else {
        var v struct {
            Restriction struct {
                OnProperty struct {
                    Resource string `xml:"resource,attr"`
                } `xml:"onProperty"`
            } `xml:"Restriction"`
        }
        if err := d.DecodeElement(&v, &start); err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("can't decode node id on %+v: %w", start, err)
        }
        description.OnProperty = v.Restriction.OnProperty.Resource
    }

    return nil
}

This is of course very simplified, but shows how to decode XML in two separate structures when you know which one you need.
Obviously, since you can do whatever you want in
type ClassDescriptor struct {
    NodeID     string
    OnProperty string
}

you could replace both alternatives with a single interface of your choice.
Does this answer your question or did I misinterpret something?

This works well! I figure what I've missed is that I had to wrap Restriction in another struct and assign the the tag  xml:"Restriction" to parse it properly. I still don't know how I could access a child node directly, but this is probably something I should avoid anyway b/c it's bypassing the xml facade. Youre cleanup/restructuring of the method makes sense. My method was more explorative than representative, and now I've consolidated it in the manner you've suggested.

The data binding approach to XML processing (that is, marshalling and unmarshalling between XML and native programming language classes) typically becomes unmanageable if the data uses the full flexibility of XML. Programming languages tend to work with highly structured data, while XML can be semi-structured or unstructured. The problem can come either from variety within an instance (as in your case) or with variation over time (schema evolution, handling multiple versions). You may need to consider a different technology or programming language. XSLT and XQuery were designed for this task.

While I agree with most of what you said, “Choose a different programming language, Go can’t handle XML” doesn't sound like good advice to me.

To be honest, I'm working with quite some programming languages atm, and Go is the worst to work with - not only, but especially when it comes to flexible behavior. That said, this particular xml processor grew in Go for mutliple years, so I'm a rather committed here. But to achieve more flexibility I'm utilizing xpath at later steps, after reading the whole owl file into the rather abstract RDF struct.

Oh, interesting. What I do above would need much more code e.g. in Java. Do you mean inflexibility in serialization especially, or generally?

@eik In this particular case, I'm refering on how to represent either-or logic, and that for unmarshaling my fields must be exposed. I agree, the code to unmarshal a xml in Go is shorter, though.

In general (and not limited to xml), I really don't like that there's no way to register a (un-)marshaling functions for a given type - instead, you always need to create a type and implement the interfaces, which was causing me quite some pain in the past with generated services: they required lots of type conversion back and forward if they for example converted something from GraphQL to a internal type and from there to its database type and back. I figure that's mostly b/c types are rather difficult in Go due to the pointer complexity etc.

You could do type MySerializedType GeneratedType tough and then implement marshaling on MySerializedType. In Java I used MapStruct a lot for this. No idea, I might have to see more code to understand what you mean. Do you have something on GitHub?

@eik Yeah, that's what I did, utilizing lots of type conversions. Which was particular annoying when also pointer versions of these types came into play, and all of that needed to be covered by Go templating/code generation. I just wished I could tell, say, the MySQL driver: here's a MyStruct with a ID uuid.UUID, and here's a way to write this MyStruct into the DB or read it from there. Instead, I need to come up with a MyDBStruct with ID myDBImpl.ID field and convert MyStruct to it ... I figure this comment section is getting a bit out of hands atm. :D
